# Don't allow WhiteSpace in Angular Form

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am implementing register an user in Angular [Form register image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XkQh.jpg), it have validated maxlength and minlength before. And now, I add an validation to check enter password have white space.

```html
const form = new FormGroup<UserRegister>({
      email: new FormControl<string>(email, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,4}$')
      ]),
      password: new FormControl<string>(password, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(PASSWORD_MINLENGTH),
        Validators.maxLength(PASSWORD_MAXLENGTH),
      ]),
      confirmPassword: new FormControl<string>(confirmPassword, [
        Validators.required
      ]),
    }, {validators: [isWhiteSpace, passwordMatchValidator]});
```

```html
      <input matInput type="password" required formControlName="password" [errorStateMatcher]="errorStateMatcher"
            placeholder="{{ 'password' | translate }}">
          <mat-error *ngIf="form.hasError('required', ['password'])" [translate]="'validation.required'"
            [translateParams]="{ value: 'password' | translate }"></mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="form.hasError('isWhiteSpace', ['password'])" [translate]="'validation.isWhiteSpace'"
          [translateParams]="{ value: 'password' | translate }"></mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="form.hasError('minlength', ['password'])" [translate]="'validation.minLength'"
            [translateParams]="{ value: 'password' | translate, minLength: PASSWORD_MINLENGTH  }"></mat-error>
          <mat-error *ngIf="form.hasError('maxlength', ['password'])" [translate]="'validation.maxLength'"
            [translateParams]="{ value: 'password' | translate, maxLength: PASSWORD_MAXLENGTH  }"></mat-error>
```

But when I add function isWhiteSpace to form, validation of min-max length unactivated.
When I enter a string < minlength and have space but it show only an error about whitespace, my expectation result is show 2 errors about minlength and space.
Could anybody give me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.userForm = this.fb.group({
            username: ["", noWhitespaceValidator]
        });
    }

noWhitespaceValidator(control: FormControl) {
    const isWhitespace = (control.value || "").trim().length === 0;
    const isValid = !isWhitespace;
    return of(isValid ? null : { whitespace: true });
}
```

Then in your view simply use

```
*ngIf="userForm.get('username').hasError('whitespace')"
```

Comment: but issue that when noWhiteSpaceValidator is activated, minlength  validator is unactivated

Comment: yes, I make sure, all validations is cool (maxlength, minLength, isMatchaPassword) and I dont know when I add function isWhiteSpace into the form (i have checked this function and it's cool), when I enter the password < minlength and has a white space, it's return a error that about white space, but my expectation is both errors white space and minlenth